# Cómo puedo Compilar un Código de Python 3.x en sublimeText 3 usando xfc4-terminal o gnome-terminal

Tags: python-3.x, linux, ubuntu, sublimetext3, linux-mint

me encontraba en **linux Mint** , instale sublimetext 3 para poder usarlo con python3 y encontre en un blog una pequeña guia donde instale sublimeREPL hice una pequeña configuración de un **Sublime-Build**

```
{
    "cmd": ["python3", "-i", "-u", "$file"], "file_regex": "^[ ]File \"(...?)\", line ([0-9]*)", "selector": "source.python"
}
```

Pero resulta que solo me sirve cuando hay código que no se necesite interactuar con entrada a través del teclado , por ejemplo si quisiera elaborar un código que me pida datos que debo ingresar por el teclado la terminal incluida en la parte inferior en sublime no me permite interactuar puedo escribir pero al presionar la tecla intro no pasa nada. 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es por eso que quiero saber si hay algún código para crear un **Sublime-Build** que me permita compilar y ejecutar el código de python3 abriendo la terminal ya sea xfc4-terminal o gnome-terminal ingresar datos del teclado y luego de terminar presionar intro o cualquier tecla y que se cierre